# Key Value Pair for Java Swing JList

Tags: java, swing, key, jlist

Ive had this solution to my JComboBox to get the effect of Key/Value pairs to show text but retrive the ID, like ID=2 but text is "Banana".

I now need to implement this to a JList instead, but have trouble to get the Object from the JList returned so that i can retrive the value.

```
public class ComboItem {

    private String value;
    private String label;

    public ComboItem(String value, String label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }
}


DefaultListModel listmodel = new DefaultListModel();
JList cAktkod = new JList(listmodel);
int pos = cAktkod.getModel().getSize();

listmodel.add(pos, new ComboItem(resultSet.getString("MMCFI5"),resultSet.getString("CTTX40")));
```

But at this stage if I do

```
cAktkod.getSelectedValue();
```

It returns an Object, and I dont know how to get it to give me my ComboItem object so that i can getValue() instead

Comment: Why can't you just cast the returned object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically JList doesnt know or care what type (i.e. subclass) of Object is in the list. But if all you have put into the list are ComboItem then the Object you get out will be a ComboItem. You just need to cast it to tell the compiler what type it is.

```
Object selectedObj = cAktkod.getSelectedValue();
if (selectedObj instanceof ComboItem) {
    ComboItem selectedItem = (ComboItem) selectedObj;
}
else {
    // something has gone wrong!
}
```

Comment: You can insert any mixture of classes into a DefaultListModel so it kind of makes sense to check the type. Of course in the example given only ComboItems are added so only ComboItems will be returned.

Answer (score 5):

mre outlined one simple solution.  If you wish to avoid casting objects back to their base types, there is another approach.

- Create a **generic** `Vector` of `ComboItem`.
- Add each item of the `Vector`
- Create the `JList` using the `Vector`
- On selection, get the selected index then call `Vector.elementAt(index)` to get the corresponding object.

Comment: Hasn't JList been "genericized" in Java 7 making this unnecessary?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Possibly.  I tried 1.7 a while ago and found it would not run my DukeBox software, uninstalled it in disgust.  I decided I'll look at it again once Oracle pushes out a 1.7 JRE auto-update (that presumably will have most of the bugs ironed out).

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the generic version of your list and model, so you'd use JList<ComboItem> and DefaultListModel<ComboItem>. That way, the object you add and get back are both of type ComboItem.